# Updated: Can I split 1 live stereo input steam into 2 mono streams, in Mac OS

Tags: stereo, mono

In Mac OS ...
Can I create 2 mono audio streams (is buses the right word?) from a live stereo signal input?

I do not need to record these streams. I just want to convert 1 stereo input into 2 mono inputs, that will then be broadcast separately.

In essence, I am receiving a 2 channel signal that I would like to split, live, and reuse.

Comment: I think any DAW would work. You add 2 tracks, set one to the left channel input and one to the right channel input. The input could be a line-in or the computer's stereo mix. The real question is: what do you mean "split live and reuse"? Stereo is already 2 channel and if you aren't storing the data, what is the purpose?

Comment: I am running 2 instances of ustream on a macbook pro, each broadcasting to a separate ustream channel.

Comment: On a macbook pro, I want to split the stereo line-in signal into 2 mono channels and then feed each mono channel to a different streaming application. In this case ustream. The reason is that the the event I will be steaming with be translated simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like Soundflower would allow you to do this:

http://cycling74.com/forums/topic/record-two-separate-audio-inputs/

Answer (score -2):

You can split a stereo Channel into two mono channels in Audacity

http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Splitting_and_Joining_Stereo_Tracks

This creates two Mono Tracks, that can be exported